# How do you display tasks from a to-do list, in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make the `complete_task` page display only tasks that have been completed. The schema uses a boolean value of true when the item is checked as complete. How do I setup a method in the `task_controller.rb` file, and reference in the `task/complete_task view` to accomplish this, while still paginating the results?

Right now my `task_controller.rb` file has this for the complete_task method:

```
def complete_task
    @tasks = current_user.tasks.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end
```

This is just displaying all the user's tasks, like the index page. I'm guessing I should add a (params[:id]) to the .task part of the code? I don't know how to check the value of the task status boolean which is true or false.

The schema for tasks looks like this:

```
create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "status"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.date     "completition_date"
  end
```

My repo is [Here](https://github.com/hackmajor/Geeks2Code).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@tasks = current_user.tasks.where(status: true)`

Which will return the current_user's tasks that are complete.